# Get Paremeter from Url Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Hello there is any way to get value from url without request,

I've index.html in static folder,

Inside of index.html i'm try to redirect to my controller classes page with following

```
<a href="/requesthandler?q=myvalue">
```

Then it goes to the

> requesthandler.html

in the browser i can see

```
localhost:8080/requesthandler?q=mayvalue
```

And after that part all of my controller class ran and i've got user

agents as well after my job finished i would like to redirect to

> /myvalue.html

I can follow this if i will get parameter value from url

```
<a href="/mayvalue">
```

Summary:
I would like to visit in order of pages like that.

```
http://localhost:8080/index.html(In static folder)

http://localhost:8080/requesthandler?q=mayvalue(I'm goes there with GetMapping return string requesthandler)

http://localhost:8080/mayvalue
```

I'm really newbie about spring boot so if in thymeleaf is not enough for that, what should i do in my ApplicationRun class.

Thank you so much :)

EDIT:
my controller class like that

```
  @GetMapping("/requesthandler")
    public String requesthandler
        (
                @RequestHeader(value="User-Agent") String userAgent,
                @RequestHeader(value = "host") String host,
                Model model
                )
{

    UserAgentStringParser parser = UADetectorServiceFactory.getResourceModuleParser();
    ReadableUserAgent agent = parser.parse(userAgent);
    Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());

    this.host=host;
    this.deviceCategory=agent.getDeviceCategory().getName();
    this.operatingSystem=agent.getOperatingSystem().getName();
    this.typeName=agent.getTypeName();
    this.browserName=agent.getName();
    this.browserIcon=agent.getIcon();
    this.deviceProducer=agent.getProducer();
    this.versionNumber=agent.getVersionNumber().toVersionString();
    this.timeStampLong=timestamp.getTime();



    sendMessage(host,deviceCategory,operatingSystem,typeName,browserName,browserIcon,deviceProducer,versionNumber,timeStampLong);


    return "requesthandler";
}
```

Comment: add some code from your controller.

Comment: @MarufHassan i edited my question and i added some code (actually main part of my controller)

Answer (score 0):

You can use **@RequestParam** in method parameter of your controller.

eg:

```
@GetMapping("/requesthandler")
public String requesthandler
    (
            @RequestHeader(value="User-Agent") String userAgent,
            @RequestHeader(value = "host") String host,
            @RequestParam("q") String variableName,
            Model model
            ){
    /*Body*/
}
```

Please have a look at https://www.journaldev.com/3358/spring-requestmapping-requestparam-pathvariable-example#spring-requestparam.

Answer (score 0):

Following code may help you.

```
@GetMapping("/requesthandler")
public String requesthandler(
                @RequestParam String q,
                @RequestHeader(value="User-Agent") String userAgent,
                @RequestHeader(value = "host") String host,
                Model model){

    //your code

    return q;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get a specific query-parameter or even the whole map of query-parameters:

```
public String myHandler(
  @RequestParam(value="q") String q,
  @RequestHeader(value="User-Agent") String userAgent
) 
{
   ...
}
```

or

```
public String myHandler(
  @RequestParam Map<String, String> parms,
  @RequestHeader(value="User-Agent") String userAgent
)
{
  String q = parms.containsKey("q") ? parms.get("q") : "";
   ...
}
```

If you don't want to use the RequestHeader-Annotation, add a HttpServletRequest-Parameter to the method and get the Header from the request:

```
public String myHandler(HttpServletRequest request, @..., ...)
{
   String headerValue = request.getHeader("xyz");
   // or have a look at existing Headers with request.getHeaderNames();
   ...
}
```